# Get environment variable of other user

Tags: shell, users, environment-variables, root

Is there a way I can see the environment variable of an other user? I want to do that as root, so permissions won't be a problem I guess.

For the user himself, I use `echo $PATH` or `set | grep PATH` (or `set` when I don't remember the variable name). What would be a similar instruction for an other user?

<sub>For what it's worth, I'm on Ubuntu Server 13.04.</sub>

Comment: Users don't have environment variables, processes do. It's common for the processes executed by one user to not all have the same environment. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Gilles for example, I want to know what MAIL folder a user has. I could login as that user, then do `echo $MAIL`, but I thought there might be a shortcut.

Comment: That still doesn't define the question usefully (and for example the answer you've accepted may or may not work depending on a lot of factors). Are you looking for the default mailbox location? Are you looking for the location where the user actually receives his local mail (which may be different, and may not exist, if the user has a `.forward`)? Users often set a few variables in their `.profile` or other configuration files, and there's no way to reliably enumerate them all. Again, what problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Another option is to use `env`. Run this as `root` or with `sudo`:

```
sudo -Hiu $user env | grep $var
```

For example

```
sudo -Hiu terdon env | grep HOME
HOME=/home/terdon
```

Comment: When I log in as root and execute this command for my standard user name, I get `HOME=/root`. That's the home directory of root, but it's _not_ my standard home directory. If you want to know the environment that a particular user would get when he logs in, you have to run the startup scripts of the login shell of this particular user (and remember that his login shell may be different from your login shell).

Comment: @Uwe on what system? It works fine for me. Do you mean you log in as `root` from the login manager? It works fine if I drop to a tty and log in as `root`.

Comment: I'm on a Debian machine. I log in as uwe, open an xterm, run `env | grep HOME` and get `HOME=/home/uwe`; I execute `su` and then once more `env | grep HOME` and get `HOME=/root`, then I run `sudo -u uwe env | grep HOME` and still get `HOME=/root`.

Comment: @uwe strange. I am also on a Debian (LMDE) machine, I did the exact same process you described (even used `xterm` instead of my usual terminal) and get the expected result.

Comment: According to the manual, `sudo` sets the HOME variable only if the `-H` option is present or if the corresponding entry in `/etc/sudoers` is set. It seems that our sudoers files differ. Anyway, it's probably a good idea to use `-H` here, and possibly also `-i`.

Comment: @Uwe ah, yes, I have `Defaults    env_reset` in my `/etc/sudoers`, that might explain the difference. Anyway added `-Hi` to be on the safe side.

Comment: if you only want to get the value out of that, you can do `sudo -Hiu $user env | grep $var | cut -d '=' -f 2`

Comment: When I try to do this as user `root` for user `www-data`, I get this error: `This account is currently not available.`

Comment: @NathanWailes if you have a new question, please [ask it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) separately. That way you can give us the necessary context. Normally, however, `www-data` doesn't have a login shell, so cannot be used with `sudo`. If you ask a new question, explaining what you need, we should be able to find a workaround.

Comment: @terdon Thanks, I'll do that now.

Answer (score 2):

For one user, you can do like this:

```
su - <username> -c '. ~/.profile; echo $PATH'
```

List $PATH of all user:

```
for user in $(cat /etc/passwd | awk -F: '{print $1}'); do
  su - $user -c '. ~/.profile; printf "%s\n" "$PATH"'
done
```

**@Camil Staps**

`. ~/.profile` is thus a trick I learn from my favourite person, Peteris Krumins. He explained the trick [here](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/chroot-su-sh-trick/) . Maybe later bash version had building with option `NON_INTERACTIVE_LOGIN_SHELLS`.

Comment: Thanks! For `$PATH` it also works without the `. ~/.profile; ` part - what is it for?

Comment: @CamilStaps What do you mean by "it works"? Yes, you get a value for `$PATH` even without sourcing `~/.profile`, but it's almost certainly not the one that you want (= the value that this user would see when he logged in). Even sourcing `~/.profile` isn't fully reliable, since the user might use a shell whose startup file is different from `~/.profile`.

Comment: @Uwe I got the same output without, but I guess that's just a coincidence then.

Comment: You're assuming the user is not using csh.

Comment: @CamilStaps The first question is whether that particular user modifies his PATH in his `~/.profile` at all. But in any case, the behavior of `sudo` can be configured quite a lot in `/etc/sudoers` (see my discussion with terdon), so when our systems behave  differently, that's probably caused by differences in the configuration files.

Comment: Here's another variation on the theme: `su - $user -c env | grep ^PATH= | cut -d'=' -f2-`, so to use it in a script.. `some_user_path=$(su - ${user} -c env | grep ^PATH= | cut -d'=' -f2-)`

Answer (score 0):

from root you can `su -` to the user and then grep the environment variable that you want to see:

`su - <username> -c 'echo $PATH'`

Comment: for some reason this doesn't work for me, even if command is executed as a different user. I ended up using "env", so sth like `runuser -l <username> -c "env | grep <var>" | cut -d '=' -f 2` works fine for me. If you're not root, need to prefix command with `sudo`.