# run command as other while loading environment variables of user

Tags: sudo

I am trying to run a script as another user, with the user's `.bashrc` properly loaded (it is a python script and it relies on `$PYTHONPATH` being properly set).

I tried everything I found for example [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78061/get-environment-variable-of-other-user), but the best I could coax out of the system was an empty `$PYTHONPATH` (which is better than my original, where it actually used my `$PYTHONPATH`).

The usecase is that I'm teaching students about shebangs and paths and whatnot, and I wanted an automated way of checking whether their script are ok or not. I can check them by dropping into their envs with `sudo su <username>`, but that is very tedious.

How can I execute a script as another user, with their environment loaded the same as if I used `sudo su <username>` and then ran it myself?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's what python virtual environments are good for.
Creating isolated and portable environments for each single python project.
No `PYTHONPATH` needed.
You could put all projects to a share for all users and switch between projects envs.
If using version control just clone a project to your own environment and go from there.
You can find many howtos in the web.

Otherwise
`sudo su <username> -c python /somepath/somescript.py` should at least run somescript in a oneliner.

**UPDATE:**
add the `-l` switch. Check the env with

`sudo su -l foo -c printenv`

Add Pythonpath like this to `/home/foo/.bashrc`
`export PYTHONPATH=/banana`

the oneliner starting the script is
`sudo su -l <username> -c python /somepath/somescript.py`

Comment: Unfortunately, your oneliner will not load environment variables :(

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work either. Actually, if I `-c "echo $PYTHONPATH"` I see my own `PYTHONPATH` not <username>'s.

Comment: is the env var exported? check `sudo su -l <username> -c printenv`

Comment: Sorry about the slow response. Yes it does, HOME and USER are e.g. set, but no export in `.bashrc` is showing up.

Comment: Ah, but if I set something in `.profile` it does get set. I think I might be confused on what gets loaded when.

Comment: But if I log in with `sudo su <username>` `.profile` is not loaded, but `.bashrc` is.

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38175/difference-between-login-shell-and-non-login-shell